# 'if' and 'for' loop questions

Tags: if-statement, for-loop, while-loop

This will be my last question for the evening and a while. I have worked my way through a 100 mark Java assessment and I am now stuck on my final two points. If anyone could help me out, it would be greatly appreciated. I am tired, feeling like a grade-A nub and just want it over with!

**Study the two instance methods below and then select only the options that are correct.**

```
public char[] methodA()
{
  char[] alphas = {'s', 't', 'e', 'a', 'm'};
  char temp = alphas[0];
  int i = 0;
  while (i < alphas.length - 1)//1
  {
    alphas[i] = alphas[i+1]; //2
    i++;
  }
  alphas[alphas.length-1]=temp;
  return alphas;
}
public char methodB()
{
  char [] alphas = {'s','a','u','s','a','g','e'};
  char first = alphas[0];
  for (int i= 1; i < alphas.length; i++) //3
  {
    if (alphas[i] < first) //4
    {
      first = alphas[i];
    }
  }
  return first;
}
```

1. The assignment statement labelled //2 will put a copy of the char
   element one to the right of the current element in alphas into the
   current element in alphas.
2. The for loop header labelled //3 will be evaluated 7 times.
3. The if statement labelled //4 will update the value held by the
   variable first if the value held in the current element in alphas
   comes before the current value of first.
4. The boolean condition in the line labelled //1 will evaluate to
   false repeatedly until i takes the value 4.
5. The returned value on invoking methodA is a char array containing
   the values 't', 'e',    'a', 'm' and 's'.
6. The returned value from invoking methodB is the character 'u'.

I believe 1 to be true. Not sure why.
I think 2 is false as the for loop is evaluated 6x, not 7.
Not sure on 3 or 4.
5 I got to be true 
6 I got to be false.

If anyone can help I owe them a beer, a cookie and a cuddle!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It is true because `alphas[i] = alphas[i+1]` essentially will take element at position `i` and and replace it with the next element in the array at `i + 1` (or another way to say it, its adjacent element).
2. I believe this is false, the keyword here is `evaluated`. A loop will evaluate to the stopping point, check the exiting condition, then kick out. So it will finish evaluating 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, **7** <--- evaluates the value and kicks
3. This will be true. the expression `if (alphas[i] < first)` is asking if the value stored in `first` is greater than the value in `alphas[i]` or inversely ... if `alphas[i]` is less than `first`. This is essentially performing a max/min algorithm because the final number in `first` will be the smallest value in the `alphas` array. In this case, the letters will be evaluated based upon their ascii values.
4. This is false. The expression will evaluate to true until 4. If this were not the case then the question 1 would not be true because it would simply throw an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.
5. This is true, because it is taking the adjacent char and placing it in the current position, then the line  `alphas[alphas.length-1]=temp` puts the first char into the last position. More specifically, after the while your array will look like this: `{ t, e, a, m, m }` then after the last line it will complete the set with `{ t, e, a, m, s }`
6. The last one is false. Like I mentioned in question 3, it is essentially performing a min search. the character `u` has a greater valued ascii value than any other letter in the sequence. `a` is the lowest letter in the set.

Great job on making an attempt.

Comment: Thank you very much! I really appreciate you taking the time to do that for me. The explanations are great, they make sense. As for the making an attempt comment, I hope you weren't being sarcastic, as I have genuinely spent a lot of time on this question :(

Regardless, you have helped me out a great deal and can call me whatever you please. IOU 1x cuddle :)

Comment: @Ali No that was genuine. Not sarcasm.

Comment: Thank you. Ha if I wasn't just about to crawl into bed, i'd say you'd made my day!

Answer (score 0):

1 is true (a[i+1] is to the right of a[i], so a[i] = a[i+1] copies the value on the right to the current)

2 is true because the loop condition is evaluated 7 times -- 6 times as true causing the body to be executed 6 times, and then 1 time as false to break the loop.

3 sounds true, a value like 'b' is considered to "come before" a value like 'd' (comparing numeric ascii codes)

4 is true because the condition 4 < (5 - 1) is false

5 is true as you think

6 is false - should return 'a'

please skip the cuddle!

Comment: Sure you don't want that cuddle? I think I love you.
Thanks a lot for taking the time out to do that for me, I appreciate it. 

Seems like a lot of true answers compared to what they usually throw in but I'll take your word for it :D

Thanks again!

Comment: Reading the question it looks like the correct answer to 4 is false.  If you read my answer, I try to explain my reasoning.